# How does django model handle db_column == foreign_key attribute name?

Tags: python, django

I'm familiar that if you set `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`, you can do

```
model_object.user = user
# or
model_object.user_id = user.pk
```

but what if you set the db_column name as the same as the attribute name, e.g.

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='created_by')
# so django uses created_by as the table column's name instead of created_by_id
```

So how do you assign the attribute using an object (`user`) vs an pk (`user.pk`)?